# Restore subset of variables in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am training a Generative Adversarial Network (GAN) in tensorflow, where basically we have two different networks each one with its own optimizer.

```
self.G, self.layer = self.generator(self.inputCT,batch_size_tf)
self.D, self.D_logits = self.discriminator(self.GT_1hot)

...

self.g_optim = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(self.learning_rate_tensor, 0.9).minimize(self.g_loss, global_step=self.global_step)

self.d_optim = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.learning_rate, beta1=0.5) \
                      .minimize(self.d_loss, var_list=self.d_vars)
```

The problem is that I train one of the networks (g) first, and then, I want to train g and d together. However, when I call the load function:

```
self.sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
self.sess.graph.finalize()

self.load(self.checkpoint_dir)

def load(self, checkpoint_dir):
    print(" [*] Reading checkpoints...")

    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(checkpoint_dir)
    if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
        ckpt_name = os.path.basename(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        self.saver.restore(self.sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I have an error like this (with a lot more traceback):

```
Tensor name "beta2_power" not found in checkpoint files checkpoint/MR2CT.model-96000
```

I can restore the g network and keep training with that function, but when I want to star d from scratch, and g from the the stored model I have that error.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To restore a subset of variables, you must create a new [`tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops/saving_and_restoring_variables#Saver.__init__) and pass it a specific list of variables to restore in the optional `var_list` argument.

By default, a `tf.train.Saver` will create ops that (i) save every variable in your graph when you call [`saver.save()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops/saving_and_restoring_variables#Saver.save) and (ii) lookup (by name) every variable in the given checkpoint when you call [`saver.restore()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops/saving_and_restoring_variables#Saver.restore). While this works for most common scenarios, you have to provide more information to work with specific subsets of the variables:

1. If you only want to restore a subset of the variables, you can get a list of these variables by calling [`tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope=G_NETWORK_PREFIX)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/framework/graph_collections#get_collection), assuming that you put the "g" network in a common [`with tf.name_scope(G_NETWORK_PREFIX):`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/framework/utility_functions#name_scope) or [`tf.variable_scope(G_NETWORK_PREFIX):`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops/sharing_variables#variable_scope) block. You can then pass this list to the `tf.train.Saver` constructor.
2. If you want to restore a subset of the variable and/or they variables in the checkpoint have **different names**, you can pass a dictionary as the `var_list` argument. By default, each variable in a checkpoint is associated with a *key*, which is the value of its `tf.Variable.name` property. If the name is different in the target graph (e.g. because you added a scope prefix), you can specify a dictionary that maps string keys (in the checkpoint file) to `tf.Variable` objects (in the target graph).

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem when restoring only part of my variables from a checkpoint and some of the saved variables did not exist in the new model.
Inspired by @Lidong answer I modified a little the reading function:

```
def get_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(file_name,all_tensors=True,tensor_name=None):
varlist=[]
var_value =[]
reader = pywrap_tensorflow.NewCheckpointReader(file_name)
if all_tensors:
  var_to_shape_map = reader.get_variable_to_shape_map()
  for key in sorted(var_to_shape_map):
    varlist.append(key)
    var_value.append(reader.get_tensor(key))
else:
    varlist.append(tensor_name)
    var_value.append(reader.get_tensor(tensor_name))
return (varlist, var_value)
```

and added a loading function:

```
def build_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(loaded_tensors):
full_var_list = list()
# Loop all loaded tensors
for i, tensor_name in enumerate(loaded_tensors[0]):
    # Extract tensor
    try:
        tensor_aux = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(tensor_name+":0")
    except:
        print('Not found: '+tensor_name)
    full_var_list.append(tensor_aux)
return full_var_list
```

Then you can simply load all common variables using:

```
CHECKPOINT_NAME = path to save file
restored_vars  = get_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(file_name=CHECKPOINT_NAME)
tensors_to_load = build_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(restored_vars)
loader = tf.train.Saver(tensors_to_load)
loader.restore(sess, CHECKPOINT_NAME)
```

Edit: I am using tensorflow 1.2

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by @mrry, I propose a solution for this problem.
To make it clear, I formulate the problem as restoring a subset of the variable from the checkpoint, when the model is built on a pre-trained model.
First, we should use print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file function from the library [inspect_checkpoint](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/python/tools/inspect_checkpoint.py) or just simply extract this function by:

```
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
def print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(file_name, tensor_name, all_tensors):
    varlist=[]
    reader = pywrap_tensorflow.NewCheckpointReader(file_name)
    if all_tensors:
      var_to_shape_map = reader.get_variable_to_shape_map()
      for key in sorted(var_to_shape_map):
        varlist.append(key)
    return varlist
varlist=print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file(file_name=the path of the ckpt file,all_tensors=True,tensor_name=None)
```

Then we use tf.get_collection() just like @mrry saied:

```
variables = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)
```

Finally, we can initialize the saver by:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(variable[:len(varlist)])
```

The complete version can be found at my github: https://github.com/pobingwanghai/tensorflow_trick/blob/master/restore_from_checkpoint.py

In my situation, the new variables are added at the end of the model, so I can simply use [:length()] to identify the needed variables, for a more complex situation, you might have to do some hand-alignment work or write a simple string matching function to determine the required variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate instance of `tf.train.Saver()` with the `var_list` argument set to the variables you want to restore.
And create a separate instance to save the variables