# How to cut pretrained TensorFlow model?

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose we have a pretrained TensorFlow model saved on disk. This model represents an autoencoder, a convolutional NN with the smallest layer in the center:

```
def autoencoder(inputs):
  # encoder part
  net = lays.conv2d(inputs, 32, [5, 5], stride=2, padding='SAME')
  net = lays.conv2d(net, 16, [5, 5], stride=2, padding='SAME')
  net = lays.conv2d(net, 8, [5, 5], stride=4, padding='SAME')
  # decoder part
  net = lays.conv2d_transpose(net, 16, [5, 5], stride=4, padding='SAME')
  net = lays.conv2d_transpose(net, 32, [5, 5], stride=2, padding='SAME')
  net = lays.conv2d_transpose(net, 1, [5, 5], stride=2, padding='SAME',activation_fn=tf.nn.tanh)
  return net
```

More detailed description of autoencoder is here :
http://machinelearninguru.com/deep_learning/tensorflow/neural_networks/autoencoder/autoencoder.html

Now we want to use this saved model as a features detector, so we need to cut it, because  we will use  only the 'encoder part' after training. How can I do it in a smart way with saving variables, tensors, operations for further normal working?

Comment: Returning the tensor of the bottleneck layer might just do it, right?

Comment: If you're not trying to save space you can be lazy and just reload the whole model. When you use the encoder to compute the constriction point tensorflow will not use the decoder component. It won't cost you any computation overhead, just a little memory. Otherwise you're probably looking at something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41621071/restore-subset-of-variables-in-tensorflow

Comment: Thanks, this approach seems to be reasonable.