# Tensorflow object detection API: How to isolate the backbone network?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection-api

I'm a user of Tensorflow Object Detection API. I use it a lot to train models like Faster-RCNN on my images. From what I understand, there is a backbone network (in my experiences, ResNet) used to extract features.

I would like to re-use the weight of this specific network, but when I save my model, it's a Faster RCNN model and, even after hours in the documentation and in the source files, I don't see how to isolate the weight of the backbone network.

Is something somebody else already has realized before ? Or is Tensorflow OD API not the right tool for what I need ?

Thank you for your help or advises !

Comment: What exactly do you mean under 'isolate'? Save the backbone weights separately from others?

Comment: Thank for your answer, I would like to load only the weight from the feature extractor. From my research, It seems that the solution is to save separatly these variables in a separate checkpoint ,and then load them in a new model after

Comment: You can restore only a subset of weights from your saved Faster-RCNN checkpoint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41621071/restore-subset-of-variables-in-tensorflow