# how to save a lot of variables with tf.train.Checkpoint

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I can save two variables(v1,v2) in checkpoints(https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/checkpoints#manually_inspecting_checkpoints) with the following way. But if I have many variables(v3,v4 ...), how to  do that? If I use the same way(v1=v1,v2=v2,v3=v3,v4=v4..) there are so many parameters. Is there one convenient way to do that?for example, since tf.train.Checkpoint can accept keras object, can I put all variables in one object?

```
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.1)
net = Net()

v1 = tf.get_variable("v1", [3], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)
v2 = tf.get_variable("v2", [5], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer)


ckpt = tf.train.Checkpoint(step=tf.Variable(1), optimizer=opt, net=net,v2=v2,v1=v1)
manager = tf.train.CheckpointManager(ckpt, './tf_ckpts', max_to_keep=3)
ckpt.restore(manager.latest_checkpoint)
if manager.latest_checkpoint:
  print("Restored from {}".format(manager.latest_checkpoint))
else:
  print("Initializing from scratch.")

for example in toy_dataset():
  loss = train_step(net, example, opt)
  ckpt.step.assign_add(1)
  if int(ckpt.step) % 10 == 0:
    save_path = manager.save()
    print("Saved checkpoint for step {}: {}".format(int(ckpt.step), save_path))
    print("loss {:1.2f}".format(loss.numpy()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me rephrase your question to make sure I understand it correct: "how to save many tf variables in checkpoint?".

If it so then my answer would be to put all of those variables into scope and access them in the manner proposed in this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/41642426/11708498